# TFS 2013 user queries in TFS SQL DB not the same as wiqadmin

Tags: tfs

System: 
In my TFS 2013 upd 4 server

Issue: 
When I query the DB for the number of user queries it returns an astonishing 8000+ results.

When I run the same list using wiqadmin.exe I get a list of 1300 user queries.

Questions: 
Can anyone explain the difference in results?
Could this become an issue with the database and how to clean up the SQL DB entries if necessary?

Thanks
-Shawn J>

Comment: One thing of note is in the default collection DB the dbo.QueryItems has query entries for users that no longer exist and many of the entries has a fDeleted = 1.  Is there a job that is supposed to clean these old entries up?

Answer (score 2):

The result from wiqadmin.exe will list the valid work item queries. However query the DB directly will return all records(including temporary files and deleted user's query)

Also it's not suggest to query the original database in TFS and also not recommend to modifying the database data.

Comment: It's more than "not recommended" @patric-msft. Doing so invalidates any support you may receive from microsoft for that instance of TFS. You would be on your own...